# fastlane -v command shows Ignoring executable-hooks-1.6.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, fastlane

I am using ruby version 3.0.0 and fastlane version 2.197.

How can I fix this?

After running the gem pristine digest-crc --version 0.6.4, it not resolved

```
fastlane -v 
Ignoring digest-crc-0.6.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine digest-crc --version 0.6.4
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.8 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.8
fastlane installation at path:
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.197.0/bin/fastlane
-----------------------------
[⠋]  Ignoring executable-hooks-1.6.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.1
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0
[✔]  
fastlane 2.197.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error:

*(The error started to appear after I upgraded to macOS Monterey.)*

```
 Ignoring clocale-0.0.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine clocale --version 0.0.4
```

For me the problem was the rights of the `Gems` folder.

I solved it with:

```sh
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Library/Ruby/Gems
```

---

followed by the suggested command:

```sh
gem pristine clocale --version 0.0.4
```

Comment: In the Gems what is the version for this?  cd /Library/Ruby/Gems
 Gems % ls
2.6.0
Mine is 2.6.0

Comment: I am using m1 machine

Comment: The above not worked for me in m1 machine (Big Sur)

Comment: In the Gems folder, I also have the version 2.6.0. I don't know if this makes any difference, I have an Intel Mac (with macOS Monterey now).